# How do I write data into specific columns of an existing file with R?

Tags: r

I have a file called otu with many columns. Within the file otu, I want to append a column of data into a specific existing column and write it into the file.  The data to be appended comes from the file, map, and each row in map should be added as a column into the corresponding column in the file otu. If the row does not exist in map, I want nothing to be appended.

So far I have created a vector called newCol, which contains the data of the columns in the specific order of the file otu.  I want to be able to write a specific column contained in the vector newCol, and write it to the existent column within the file otu.

I also understand newCol is a vector and want to know what data type I should use to hold columns as well as how to write the columns into the specific existing columns in file otu.

Heres what I've gotten so far, I've created the vector newCol which holds all my data in the correct order.

```
#newCol holds columns of data copied from file named "map"
newCol<-c()
#Loop over the columns of the file named "otu"
for (col in colnames(otu)){
  #check if each column header col is a row name of the file "map"
  if (is.element(col, rownames(map))){
    #if True, the row of name col in file map should be transposed and concatenated to variable newCol
    newCol<- c(newCol, t(map[col,]))

  #if False, concatenate "" because the row name col does not exist as a row in the map file

    }else{
    #if the col is not in the header, NA is added
    newCol<- c(newCol, "")

    }

}
```

So, I'm attempting to copy the otu file into a new variable called newOTU, append to the columns of the newOTU, and then print the entire newOTU to a new file.

However I get the error newOTU[, col] : incorrect number of dimensions.

```
#newCol holds columns of data copied from file named "map"
newOTU <- otu
newCol<-c()
#Loop over the columns of the file named "otu"
for (col in colnames(otu)){
  #check if each column header col is a row name of the file "map"
  if (is.element(col, rownames(map))){
    #if True, the row of name col in file map should be transposed and concatenated to column col in newOTU
    newOTU[,col] <- append(newOTU[,col], t(map[col,]))

    }

}
write.table(newOTU, file = "test.txt", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = "\t",
        eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
        col.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: if the file isn't huge, you can just overwrite the whole thing. If there's another way. I'd like to know as well.

Comment: why not load both into R and manipulate?

Comment: The problem is I don't want to overwite the file.  I want to append a column of data to an existing column of data, but just for specific columns